# Issue with a resize function after ajax refresh

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Im having issues with combining 2 scripts
I have javascript code that checks how big my container is and if its bigger than 500 it devides the content into 2 different divs:

```
function divideStream() {
            if ($("#stream_one_col").width() > 500) {
                var leftHeight = 0;
                var rightHeight = 0;

                $("#stream_one_col").children().each(function() {
                    if (rightHeight < leftHeight) {
                        $("#stream_right_col").append(this);
                        rightHeight += $(this).height();
                        $(this).children().addClass("stream_right_inner");
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#stream_left_col").append(this);
                        leftHeight += $(this).height();
                        $(this).children().addClass("stream_left_inner");
                    }                               
                });
            }
            else {
                $("#content_left").load("php/stream_left.php");
            }
        }
```

And I have an ajax refresh

```
$(document).ready(
        function() {
            setInterval(function() {
                $('.aroundit').load('php/stream_left.php');
            $(".aroundit").divideStream();
            }, 3000);
        });
```

Now basically the reloading goes just fine
However, the function (divideStream) wont reload after the ajax is activated
Instead it just keeps jumping back and forth
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand what is happening.  But I think you might want to make sure that you run your divideSteam function after the load has completed.  You can do it like this.

```
 $(document).ready(
    function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            $('.aroundit').load('php/stream_left.php', function() {  //this function runs once load has completed
                divideStream();  // as hugo mentioned   
            });
        }, 3000);
    });
```

Comment: I added it after the code so it performed once the loading was done
The divideStream still had to be $(".aroundit").divideStream(); to work though but it works now, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

the function divideStream is not a extend function of jQuery .

You should use this:

```
$(document).ready(
        function() {
            setInterval(function() {
                $('.aroundit').load('php/stream_left.php');
                divideStream();
            }, 3000);
        });
```